# Query OpenFDA by UPC

Tags: openfda

I am trying to query OpenFDA by UPC but the API keeps returning "No Matched Found". I assume this works in the same way as product NDC, which is returning as expected when I try something like this:

https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=product_ndc:%2259779-612%22

When I switch "product_ndc" with "upc" I get no matching results:

https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=upc:%22300450449092%22

Am I missing something in the query? Or can the API only handle a subset of UPCs? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

We simply do not have UPCs for all the drug labels. Otherwise, searching by UPC works, e.g. https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=upc:%220098443601700%22

Comment: is this still actual or was API improved to search by UPC?

Comment: We still do not have UPCs for all the drug labels, unfortunately.